# Convert Written Math Expression to a simple Google Sheets Formula

Tags: google-sheets, math, google-sheets-formula, equation

I've been trying to write this type of equation into google sheets manually, but as i progress i will be facing longer and more complex ones.

**Here's an example :**

[image]

This Becomes : ***X=(5^(1/3)*Y^(1/3))/2^(2/3)****

This is just another way of writing it.

**Now, my question is, Is there a way to convert this automatically ?**

Here's an example of more complex translations i have to do :

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "convert this automatically" ?

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: if the source of your equations is *just* a picture, then its probably not even worth thinking about. If your source is generated from something like MathML or LaTeX then it gets easier? but still not easy.

Comment: Tenib, if you mean extracting a formula from an image, take a look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116863/image-equation-to-tex By the way, it would help others help you if you can explain more about what you need to accomplish.

Comment: @NickSlash Um, if you are not actually familiar with the problem, it's okay to just refrain from saying anything about it. It's not helpful to OP or anybody else to be unnecessarily negative.

Comment: @RobertDodier, I don't believe my comment was negative, the op has not specified the source of the equation, OCRing an image is possible but not simple. I will refrain in future, but even a non-expert can sometimes provide help.

Comment: @NickSlash I dunno, you can try to walk it back, but "its probably not even worth thinking about" is pretty flatly negative. Later you said "possible but not simple" but that's not what you were saying originally. Not a big deal; my advice is mostly just to read what you write from the point of view of another person before hitting the send button.